# Find the derivative of $y = f(x^2 - 2x + 7)$ where $f'(10) = 2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Determine the derivative if $y = f(x^2 - 2x + 7)$ and $f'(10) = 2$

Ok so honestly, I dont know how to solve this, or even know where to start. All i know is that we are given a point $(10, 2)$. But what is $f(x^2 - 2x +7)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: But y = f(x^2−2x+7). What does f(x^2−2x+7) even mean?

Comment: **Hint**: Apply the chain rule. Also, are you evaluating $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at a given point?

Comment: Here is an example let $f(x)=x^2$ and $y=f(x^2-2x+7)$ then $y=(x^2-2x+7)^2$.

Comment: @Orangutango, yeah x = 3. But how am I to use chain rule?

Comment: in many cases we have compositions of functions, where we can actually have a function that is composed of other functions.  For example, we can have $y=(x-1)^2$.  So we define $g(x)=x-1$ and we define $f(x)=x^2$.  Therefore, $f(g(x))=f(x-1)=(x-1)^2$

Comment: I think you're being asked to find out $\;y'(3)\;$ ...

Comment: So you have a new function $g(x)=f(x^2-2x+7)$. You have to make derivative of $g(x)$.... at which point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $y=f(z)$ = well $f$ can be anything. Then we put $z=x^2-2x+7$ and get a new function $g(x)=f(x^2-2x+7)$. Some examples:

$$f(z)=z; f(x^2-2x+7)=x^2-2x+7=g(x)$$

$$f(z)=z^2+3; f(x^2-2x+7)=(x^2-2x+7)^2+3=g(x)$$

$$f(z)=\sin (z); f(x^2-2x+7)=\sin (x^2-2x+7)=g(x)$$

Now we want to see what we know about the derivative of $f(x^2-2x+7)$ when it could take any one of a myriad of forms. We use the chain rule - the derivative of $p(q(x))$ is $q'(x)p'(q(x))$ with $p=f$ and $q(x)=x^2-2x+7$ to obtain the derivative $$(2x-2)f'(x^2-2x+7)$$

Now we only know $f'(10)$, so we can only deal with $$x^2-2x+7=10$$ which reduces to $$(x-3)(x+1)=0$$

So $x=3$, or $x=-1$

With $x=3$ we get $4\times 2 =8$.

With $x=-1$ we get $-4 \times 2 = -8$.

Because the form of $f$ is undefined, we can't say more than this - even that our function is differentiable in other places.

Comment: + Nice explanation, Mark!

Answer (score 3):

By the chain rule:

$$y'=f'(x^2-2x+7)(2x-2)$$

and for example

$$y'(3)=f'(3^2-2\cdot3+7)(2\cdot3-2)=f'(10)\cdot4=8$$

Comment: Isn't that $y'(3)$?

Comment: Yes, it is . Thanks.

Comment: One could also find $y'(-1)$.  OP does not tell us what the actual question is.

Comment: Indeed so, @JonasMeyer. That's one of the reasons why I proposed $\,y'(3)\;$ just by guessing...

Comment: @DonAntonio, I know what you did upto $y′(3)=f′(32−2⋅3+7)(2⋅3−2)$. $f'(10)$ - the 10 is being subbed into what part?

Comment: If you're asking where did that $\,10\,$ come from: note that $\,3^2-2\cdot3+7=10\,\ldots $